# Ubuntu 16.04: "Setting up snapd.." and dpkg freezes

Tags: apt, 16.04, dpkg, snap

I was just doing regular update:

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up snapd (2.14.2~16.04) ...
```

I had to kill dpkg process. Then after apt-get update dpkg shows message:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
gondy@***:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up snapd (2.14.2~16.04) ...
```

And it hangs again. What should I do? Do I need this package at all? I am running Ubuntu 16.04, upgraded from 14.04 LTS Server edition.

Comment: The problem is still there in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1621336), it is already fixed in -proposed. You can wait until the fix makes it's way to stable, enable testing or use a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1621336/comments/11):

1. start a rootshell with `sudo -i`
2. run `echo "bash -c 'service snapd.boot-ok start'" | at now + 4 min`
3. run `apt install snapd` (if it argues about canceled dpkg processes use  `dpkg --configure -a`)
4. wait for at least 4 minutes

Or just run `sudo service snapd.boot-ok start` from a different console after seeing `Setting up snapd...` on the first console.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, I have solved this by simply removing snapd package.. I dont need it.